# Angular angular2-jwt: Getting error using AuthHttp: JWT must have 3 parts

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-jwt

I am getting an error when I use the AuthHttp yet the authenticate returns a good token. And I verified it on https://jwt.io/ and it is good.

I am using Angular 4.
My code is as following:

SignIn Code

```
 signIn(login: string, password: string) {
    this.UserLogin.name = login;
    this.UserLogin.password = password;

    this.http.post(this.baselink + '.json', this.UserLogin, { headers: contentHeaders })
      .subscribe(
      response => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_toke', response.json().token);
        this.jwt = localStorage.getItem('id_toke');
        this.decodedJwt = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwt);
        this.userRole = this.decodedJwt.roles;
        console.log(this.userRole);
        this.useJwtHelper();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Http Error ' + error.text());
        this.router.navigate(['http-error']);
      }
      );
  }
```

> token[![enter image description
>   here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvKpf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvKpf.jpg):"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsInJvbGVzIjpbInJlYWQtb25seSIsInJlYWQtd3JpdGUiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDk2MTkxNDg4LCJleHAiOjE0OTYyMDAwODh9.qPCQY3yHujuCLb9g-F5b0MUQO3tyTr_Y5YRoMOQ0DBA"

[image]

Yet get data is throwing error

```
   getPayments() {
       return this.authHttp.get(this.baselink + '/getPayments', { headers: contentHeaders })
            .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                return data;
            }
            )
            .catch(
            (error: Response) => {
               console.log('Error getPayments: ' + error);
                return Observable.throw('Something went wrong: ' + error.text);
            }
            );
     }
```

and getting

> Error getPayments: Error: JWT must have 3 parts

Having said that if I use `return this.http.get(this.baselink + '/getPayments')` instead it works. The connection of AuthHttp is not reaching the server. That specific controller is not restricted on the server for the time being but the intention is to secure it
probably the token is not included in AuthHttp header

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
            deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
        }
    ]
})
export class AuthorizationModule { }


export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
    return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        headerPrefix: 'bearer',
        tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
        globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
        noJwtError: true
    }), http, options);
}
```

and global headers

```
export const contentHeaders = new Headers();
contentHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: **Update**
It is a server side cros issue. So apparently the browser will send 2 calls asking the server to allow that header and the server to approve it.
In my case on the server side I needed to add my url to the FilterRegistraionBean. I had it added but not correctly

Answer (score 0):

I changed my function to the below

```
getPayments():  Observable<Payment[]> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token - mine is saved in authService service in jwt variable
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.jwt });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


    return this.http.get(this.baselink + '/getPayments', options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw('Something went wrong: ' + error.text);
        });
}
```

Now getting this error

```
function (encodingHint) {
        if (encodingHint === void 0) { encodingHint = 'legacy'; }
        if (this._body instanceof URLSearchParams) {
            return this._body.toString();
        }
        if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            switch (encodingHint) {
                case 'legacy':
                    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(/** @type {?} */ (this._body)));
                case 'iso-8859':
                    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(/** @type {?} */ (this._body)));
                default:
                    throw new Error("Invalid value for encodingHint: " + encodingHint);
            }
        }
        if (this._body == null) {
            return '';
        }
        if (typeof this._body === 'object') {
            return JSON.stringify(this._body, null, 2);
        }
        return this._body.toString();
    }
```

Checking the server side, the Authorization is missing!!

**Update**
It is a server side cros issue. So apparently the browser will send 2 calls asking the server to allow that header and the server to approve it.
In my case on the server side I needed to add my url to the FilterRegistraionBean. I had it added but not correctly